# How can I load a new page with enter key?

Tags: javascript, button, key, enter

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = init;

function init() {
    var button = document.getElementById("searchbutton");
    button.onclick = handleButtonClick;
}

function handleButtonClick(e) {
    var textinput = document.getElementById("searchinput");
    var searchterm = textinput.value;
    window.location.assign("http://www.google.com/testing/" + searchterm)
}
</script>

<input type="text" name="search" id="searchinput">
<button type="button" id="searchbutton">Ara</button>
```

This code block takes a user input and goes a new page with that.

When user pressed enter key, I want to make same thing with that submit button. I find something on web but they are all related with jquery.

Comment: If you don't mind dropping support for IE, you can bind `[input#searchinput].onchange` to `handleButtonClick()` too; if you don't like that, listen to `[input#searchinput].onkeyup` and check if `[Enter]` (keyCode: 13) is pressed.

Comment: Alright, I've added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use a  tag, with a Submit button, and use the .onSubmit() event of the form. This event will be triggered both when you click and when you hit the Return (Enter) key.

An example JS code (tested in JSFiddle, just modified a bit your code to add a form) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function processForm(e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();

    var textinput = document.getElementById("searchinput");
    var searchterm = textinput.value;
    window.location.assign("http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=" + searchterm)

    return false; // Block form
}

var form = document.getElementById('searchForm');

if (form.attachEvent) { form.attachEvent("submit", processForm); } 
else { form.addEventListener("submit", processForm); }​
</script>
<form id="searchForm">
<input type="text" name="search" id="searchinput">
<input type="submit">
</form>​
```

You can watch this code live here : http://jsfiddle.net/UD8FN/

Hugo,

Comment: I'll use it for Opera extension. This will be something like this;
http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term= will be main url, user's input will go to end of url. Do you have any suggestion for this?

Comment: Imrahil, I corrected my answer, and attached a JSFiddle, where you can test the code live. I made the version with UrbanDictionary because I don't know Google's command line but it's the same, only a minor change.

Comment: I think this a better than the other forms (catching onClick, and keycode 13 events), because you rely on the browser for knowing when the form is submitted. Whatever the way used to submit the form, the JS code will be run. The other methods try to impersonate the onSubmit() event.

Answer (score 1):

Extending from comment:

An IE-unfriendly solution:

```
function init() {
    var button = document.getElementById("searchbutton");
    button.onclick = handleButtonClick;
    document.getElementById("searchinput").onchange=handleButtonClick;
}
```

A common solution:

```
function init() {
    var button = document.getElementById("searchbutton");
    button.onclick = handleButtonClick;
    document.getElementById("searchinput").onkeyup=function(e){
        e=e?e:event;
        if(e.keyCode==13) handleButtonClick();
    };
}
```

Comment: @Imrahil In the "IE-unfriendly" version, I tell the `[input#searchinput]` to handle `onchange` event as if `[button#searchbuton]` is clicked; In the common version, I tell  the `[input#searchinput]` to listen to `onkeyup` event, and see if `[Enter]` (keyCode=13) is pressed, and if it is, run `handleButtonClick()`.

Comment: @Imrahil Well it's for IE compatible. IE would not send `event` as the first parameter; instead you have to use `window.event` inside event handler. If you're just doing Opera extension, you can omit that line.

Comment: Yep, I'm doing Opera extension but if you can give more detail (or any article link) about this, I'll grateful to you.

Comment: @Imrahil What do you mean by "more detail"? I don't know anything about Opera Extension, but if you're talking about the `event` thing, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535863(VS.85).aspx) is the document from MSDN, and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event) is the document from Mozilla.

Comment: I was talking about event thing. Thanks for links.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="searchinput" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) handleButtonClick()">
```

Comment: I don't want to use inline script, how can I use it in script tag?